# Add new object to model with a foreign key

Tags: django

So this seems to be asked before but for the life of me, i cannot get any of the solutions to work.

I have two classes, Device and Log. There are many logs per device and i'd like to be able to add new items to the Log objects.

```
class Device(models.Models):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    type = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

class Log(models.Modles):
   device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='msgs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   log = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
   date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I've been trying things like this in my view:

```
device = Device.objects.filter(name=hostname)
device.msgs.add(log=new_log_msg)
```

but nothing i try is working. any ideas?

Comment: What is msg? add?

Comment: @a_k_v neither of those is the problem; `msgs` is the related name from Device to Log, and `add` is the correct way to [add a related item](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).

Comment: @daniel thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get device object as

```
device = Device.objects.filter(name=hostname) # If hostname not found throw exception
```

For creating a new log

```
log = Log.objects.create(device=device, log='')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a Device instance, but `filter` always gives a queryset. You should use `get`.

```
device = Device.objects.get(name=hostname)
device.msgs.add(log=new_log_msg)
```

Comment: I am curious about what this statement means, device.msgs.add(log=new_log_msg)

Answer (score 0):

use get instead of filter in queryset and for creating and updating the alway intitiate the instance.

```
device = Device.objects.get(name=hostname)
device.msgs.add(log=new_log_msg)
```

For adding data in log

```
Log.objects.create(device=device, log='')
```

The `device=device` is foriegn key.